# Get the data from a GET request before rendering D3.js graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to make a network graph of some data I've got in a database, I'm working on AngularJS for the front end (C# for the back end).

I found d3.js and it seems perfect, but I'm not an expert on JavaScript at all.
I took the example from him https://observablehq.com/@d3/mobile-patent-suits?collection=@d3/d3-force
(actually it must be a previous version or something someone forked from Github, and I can't find it anymore, but that's the core anyway).

My problem is, I have to load the array of JSON `var links` from the function `self.GetLinks` that calls the API and return a JSON of the same kind of object.
The function is called in `onInit`, but by the time it is called everything is already rendered on screen, and the only result of `self.GetLinks` is changing what's inside of `var links` when it is already too late.

Just to be clear the array `var links` shown here is the one I took from the example, it's useless to me but the structure is the same.

I need to understand either how to call `self.GetLinks` before anything happens so that the content of `var links` is what I actually get from the back end, or even better how to make it so that when the content of `var links` changes the graph is rendered again (this way I could dynamically add elements to it).

```
function MyController($scope, MyService, $routeParams, viewModelHelper) {

    var self = this;
    self.model = {
        id: parseInt($routeParams.Id) || -1,
        links: {},
    };

    self.$onInit = function () {
        self.GetLinks(self.model.id);
    };

     var links = [
        { source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing" },
        { source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing" },
        { source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Nokia", target: "Apple", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "HTC", target: "Apple", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Kodak", target: "Apple", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Microsoft", target: "Barnes & Noble", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Microsoft", target: "Foxconn", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Oracle", target: "Google", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Apple", target: "HTC", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Microsoft", target: "Inventec", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Samsung", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "LG", target: "Kodak", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "RIM", target: "Kodak", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Sony", target: "LG", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Kodak", target: "LG", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "Apple", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "Qualcomm", target: "Nokia", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "Apple", target: "Motorola", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Microsoft", target: "Motorola", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Motorola", target: "Microsoft", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Huawei", target: "ZTE", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Ericsson", target: "ZTE", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Kodak", target: "Samsung", type: "resolved" },
        { source: "Apple", target: "Samsung", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Kodak", target: "RIM", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Nokia", target: "Qualcomm", type: "suit" },
        { source: "Pippo", target: "Pippo" },
        { source: "Paperino", target: "Pippo", type: "suit" }
    ];

    self.GetLinks = function (id) {
        viewModelHelper.apiGet("Api/GetLinks/" + id,
            null,
            function (result) {
                links = result.data.Elements;

                var message = "Success";
                setResultMessage(message, "Info");
            },
            function (result) {

                var message = "Error " + result.data.Message;
                setResultMessage(message, "danger");
            },
            function (result) {

            });        

    };

    var nodes = {};


    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function (link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = { name: link.source });
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = { name: link.target });
    });


    var w = 1400,
        h = 900;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([w, h])
        .linkDistance(200)
        .charge(-1200)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
        .enter().append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", String)
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", -1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
        .attr("class", function (d) { return "link " + d.type; })
        .attr("marker-end", function (d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

    var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("svg:image")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("xlink:href", "/Image/icon.png")
        .attr("x", "-8px")
        .attr("y", "-8px")
        .attr("width", "50px")
        .attr("height", "50px")
        .call(force.drag);



    var text = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("g")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("svg:g");

    // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
    text.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 2)
        .attr("y", 50)//".31em"
        .attr("class", "shadow")
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    text.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 2)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

    var path_label = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll(".path_label")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "path_label")
        .append("svg:textPath")
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index; })
        .style("fill", "#000")
        .style("font-family", "Arial")
        .text(function (d) { return d.type; });

    // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
    function tick() {
        path.attr("d", function (d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        });

        circle.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

        text.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }

    function setResultMessage(message, type) {
        self.ResponseModel = {};
        self.ResponseModel.ResponseAlert = true;
        self.ResponseModel.ResponseType = type;
        self.ResponseModel.ResponseMessage = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things. The first is separate the logic into "first render" and "update" parts. In the first render part, you just assume you're drawing on a blank SVG. In the update part, you update the things that have changed, using your data.

In this example, the first render part can be used to draw the `svg` and the `defs`. Then the update part can handle drawing the nodes and links at the correct positions.

---

The second thing you need to do is look at triggering functions. This can be done in the callbacks you use now or through promises (see AngularJS' `$q` for that).

---

Finally, it's bad practice to do all this initialisation stuff not within a function or the constructor. I've split your code into a `firstRender` and and `update` part, calling `firstRender` from `$onInit`, and mocked the API to return only after 2 seconds. Note how the chart is updated after those 2 seconds.

```js
function MyController($scope) {

  var self = this;
  self.model = {
    id: -1,
    links: {},
  };

  self.$onInit = function() {
    self.GetLinks(self.model.id);
    self.firstRender();
  };

  var links = [];
  var nodes = {};
  var w = 1400,
    h = 900;
  var force;
  var svg;
  var paths;
  var circles;
  var texts;
  var pathLabels;

  self.GetLinks = function(id) {
    viewModelHelper.apiGet("Api/GetLinks/" + id,
      null,
      function(result) {
        links = result;
        self.update();
      }
    )
  };

  self.firstRender = function() {
    force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([w, h])
      .linkDistance(200)
      .charge(-1200)
      .on("tick", tick);

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
      .enter().append("svg:marker")
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    paths = svg.append("svg:g");
    circles = svg.append("svg:g");
    texts = svg.append("svg:g");
    pathLabels = svg.append("svg:g");
  }

  self.update = function() {
    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
        name: link.source
      });
      link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
        name: link.target
      });
    });

    force
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .start();

    var path = paths.selectAll("path")
      .data(force.links());

    path.exit()
      .remove();
    path.enter()
      .append("svg:path");

    path.attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index;
      })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link " + d.type;
      })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
      });

    // var circle = circles.selectAll(".circle")
    //   .data(force.nodes());
    //
    // circle.exit()
    //   .remove();
    // circle.enter()
    //   .append("svg:image")
    //   .attr("class", "circle")
    //   .attr("xlink:href", "/Image/icon.png")
    //   .attr("x", "-8px")
    //   .attr("y", "-8px")
    //   .attr("width", "50px")
    //   .attr("height", "50px")
    //   .call(force.drag);
    var circle = circles.selectAll(".circle")
      .data(force.nodes());

    circle.exit()
      .remove();
    circle.enter()
      .append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r", 16)
      .call(force.drag);

    var text = texts.selectAll("g")
      .data(force.nodes());

    text.exit()
      .remove();
    text.enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", 50) //".31em"

    text.text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

    var pathLabel = pathLabels
      .selectAll(".path_label")
      .data(force.links());

    pathLabel.exit().remove();
    pathLabel.enter()
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("class", "path_label")
      .append("svg:textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .style("font-family", "Arial");

    pathLabel
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return "#" + d.source.index + "_" + d.target.index;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.type;
      });
  }

  // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
  function tick() {
    paths.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });

    circles.selectAll("circle").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    texts.selectAll("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
  }
}

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", MyController);

var viewModelHelper = {
  apiGet: function(a, b, then) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        console.log("Response from server");
        then(viewModelHelper.links);
      },
      2000
    );
  },
  links: [{
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Amazon",
      type: "licensing"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "HTC",
      type: "licensing"
    },
    {
      source: "Samsung",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Motorola",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Nokia",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "HTC",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "Apple",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Barnes & Noble",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Foxconn",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Oracle",
      target: "Google",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "HTC",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Inventec",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Samsung",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "LG",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "RIM",
      target: "Kodak",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Sony",
      target: "LG",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "LG",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Nokia",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Qualcomm",
      target: "Nokia",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Motorola",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Microsoft",
      target: "Motorola",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Motorola",
      target: "Microsoft",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Huawei",
      target: "ZTE",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Ericsson",
      target: "ZTE",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "Samsung",
      type: "resolved"
    },
    {
      source: "Apple",
      target: "Samsung",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Kodak",
      target: "RIM",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Nokia",
      target: "Qualcomm",
      type: "suit"
    },
    {
      source: "Pippo",
      target: "Pippo"
    },
    {
      source: "Paperino",
      target: "Pippo",
      type: "suit"
    }
  ],
};
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time, I tried it and it is working.
Would you mind if I ask some clarifications just so I understand better what's happening here?

1 - about the var viewModelHelper : why is it defined outside the controller? Why do we declare the array here?
 If I have to write more functions using viewModelHelper, will they all be delayed by 2 second?

2 - I don't know if you're an expert on d3/svg, but do you know any resources on how to implement features like a right click menu on the graph?

Comment: This is just a dummy function that is meant to mock an API call. Of course, I have no real server, so what I did was just make the data object available only after 2000 milliseconds. This way, the chart would already have been drawn, so you should be able to see it update from getting the new data

Comment: d3 has excellent event handlers. I've never used them with right click specificially, but it supports click, hover, touch, keypress, and much more. See [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/tree/v1.4.1#selection_on) for the documentation

Comment: Do you mean that if I go into the ApiController and I put a ThreadSleep(2000) into it I can remove that dummy function outside of the controller?

Comment: No, if you replace it with the regular API call you had, you can remove the dummy function. No need to put threadsleep anywhere, it was just for demonstration purposes